# Android TabActivity

Tags: android, layout, android-tabhost, tabactivity

Hello 
I try to make layout like this :

```
--------------------|
|Tab1 | Tab2 | Tab3 |
--------------------|
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
--------------------|
```

Inside Tab1 I want another Tabs

```
--------------------|
|Tab1 | Tab2 | Tab3 |
--------------------|
|TAB A   |  TAB B   |
--------------------|                        |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
--------------------|
```

I use xml files : main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">      


        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

and tablevel2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</TabHost>
```

But it doesn't work, because content in TabB overlap content from tab1. Conent is other acitivity.